# Create test data in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Im trying to create some very simple test data with the following query.
However I need the numbers to on separate rows

```
SELECT
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] as id,
[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,3,4] as col_2
```

Wanted result:

```
row  id    col_2
0    0        3
1    1        4
2    2        5
```

etc ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In standard SQL use `WITH OFFSET`, `OFFSET(index)` and `row_number() over()` functions:

```
WITH data AS (
SELECT
   [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] as id,
   [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,3,4] as col_2
) 
SELECT row_number() over() - 1 , id, col_2[OFFSET(off)] as col_2 
FROM data, unnest(id) as id WITH OFFSET off;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following Query:-

```
WITH your_data AS (
SELECT
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] as id)
select  id_member from your_data 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(id) as id_member
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select id, col_2 
from `project.dataset.table`, 
unnest(id) id with offset
join unnest(col_2) col_2 with offset 
using(offset)
```

if applied to sample data from your question - output is

[image]